# How do I escape a password ending with a dollar sign icinga2?

Tags: icinga2

I have dozens of devices I need to login to using an API script. One set of devices has a password ending in $. I've tried a bunch of things but I can't seem to escape that $ char. Here is the error I'm seeing.

```
critical/config: Error: Validation failed for object 'gelt-uk4-gp!HTTP/80: Status Check ' of type 'Service'; Attribute 'vars' -> 'gspass': Closing $ not found in macro format string 'n0t-real#$'.
Location: in /etc/icinga2/zones.d/global-templates/global-services.conf: 55:5-55:31
/etc/icinga2/zones.d/global-templates/global-services.conf(53):   if ( host.vars.company == "gelt-emea" ) {
/etc/icinga2/zones.d/global-templates/global-services.conf(54):     vars.gsuser = "admin"
/etc/icinga2/zones.d/global-templates/global-services.conf(55):     vars.gspass = "n0t-real#$"
                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I have other zones whose credentials do not contain control characters and they work fine. I sure wish I could change this particular password but I am not allowed to.

Comment: I have a per-zone {zone_name}-credentials.conf in each zone.d directory.
They have lines in them like so:

`template Service "gelt-emea-credentials" {`
  `vars.GELTGSUSER = "admin"`
  `vars.GELTGSPASS = "n0t-real#$"`

Answer (score 6):

You add an extra `$` right beside the literal dollar sign.
So if the password is `word54s$` you type:

```
vars.geltpass = "word54s$$"
```

Comment: This also works if you need to specify a regular expression (`^...$`) in a variable.